# WebSecurity issue : Initialize database connection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, linq-to-sql

I got an issue while trying to put in place a authentication system. I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 and Linq to SQL Classes.

First of all, there is a login view which calls the related controller. This is what I'm doing to connect and redirect my users following their roles.

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Login/
    T2A_DataClassesDataContext db;

    public LoginController()
    {
        db = new T2A_DataClassesDataContext();
    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult Index(LoginViewModel lvm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (WebSecurity.Login(lvm.Username, lvm.Password, false))
            {
                var login = from u in db.Users where u.Username == lvm.Username select new User { Username = u.Username, Password = u.Password, IsAdmin = u.IsAdmin };

                User user = (User)login;

                String role = user.IsAdmin == true ? "Utilisateur" : "Administrateur";

                return RedirectToAction("Index", role);

            }

            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Identifiants erronés !");
            }
        }

        return View();
    }

}
```

When I compile the solution, enter the right credentials and submit it, it fails and this is what I got :

> You must call the "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method before you call any other method of the "WebSecurity" class. This call should be placed in an _AppStart.cshtml file in the root of your site.

I know that the message is pretty clear but I don't know how to proceed to do that. Any help guys?

Answer (score 0):

`WebSecurity. InitializeDatabaseConnection` will prime your database to be used by the membership provider by creating necessary tables. So you have to call it before calling any other feature of WebSecurity. In your application, locate `Application_Start` ( in `Global.ascx.cs`) and have the initialization code called in it. For example

```
if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("yourConnectionStringInConfigFile","UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

`yourConnectionStringInConfigFile` would be your connection string in webconfig. After calling the above code, WebSecurity will create a table by the name UserProfile along with the other required tables.

Good luck